# xhtml support in pisa v3.0.33

Tags: python, xhtml, pisa

I am trying to convert html to pdf using pisa. I am using the following line of code -

```
pisa.CreatePDF(htmlCode, pdfFile, xhtml=True )
```

I get the following error. 
    pdf creation failed with error 'module' object has no attribute 'XHTMLParser'

I have html5lib 1.0b3 installed.  It used to work before but something happened (may be I updated some of the modules).  So does any one know why I keep getting the above error?

When I do not pass the "xhtml=True", the call succeeds but the pdf generated is all wrong.
Can I get around this somehow? Is it possible to convert a web page from xhtml to html?

How do I know whether a particular page is in xhtml or not?

The last two questions might not make sense because I do not write html code and can only read it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There is no `XHTMLParser` in html5parser](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python/blob/master/html5lib/__init__.py), and the [source code of pisa](https://github.com/chrisglass/xhtml2pdf/blob/5fbe1d0017b3201e8ca9bf0172bd02c8a7a89c63/xhtml2pdf/parser.py#L632) indicates that the `xhtml=True` flag is permanently broken:

```
if xhtml:
    #TODO: XHTMLParser doesn't see to exist...
    parser = html5lib.XHTMLParser(tree=treebuilders.getTreeBuilder("dom"))
```

Fortunately, XHTML is often valid HTML as well, so you don't need any conversion. Therefore, simply [find out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=python%20pisa%20xhtmltopdf&title=PDF%20rendered%20wrong) why *the pdf generated is all wrong* - XHTML is not the problem here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly the pointers I was hoping to get. I will check what is happening with the pdf creation. Thanks for the link to the pisa code as well.

Comment: "XHTML is always valid HTML". No it isn't. `<div><span /></div>`